# TFS 2012 with SharePoint - migration of one collection

Tags: sharepoint, tfs

I have TFS 2012 integrated with SharePoint and many collections in it.

Question: Is it possible to migrate exactly one collection with whole data in SharePoint to other server with already existing collections and integrated SharePoint?

I know that it's possible to migrate collection without SharePoint, but I want to restore SP data and don't lose existing SP data on destination server.

Comment: You can use `Backup-SPSite` and `Restore-SPSite` powershell cmd, but remember that restore overwrite destination data of specified collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can use powershell to export a single site/collection from SharePoint and restore it to the new location. You will likely have to rebind all of the Team Project / SharePoint site relationships but there is powershell out there for that if you have Manny...

Move Sharepoint Site: http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/sharepoint-designer-help/back-up-restore-or-move-a-sharepoint-site-HA010069939.aspx

Rebind Team Project and Sharepoint: ?? Can't find scripts

Answer (score -1):

You certainly have plenty of options out there between database detach and attach and 3rd party migration tools).

Most tools will allow you to preserve the metadata (authors and timestamps) along with the structure and content of your site collection.

I invite you to evaluate the different offers, all majors companies offer trials. You will find Sharegate's trial [here](http://en.share-gate.com/)

I am certainly biased because I work at Sharegate but the best advice I can give you is to run tests with the trials offered so you have all the information needed to take an educated decision.

The detach/attach approach is also possible, here is how to do it if you select to go down that road: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30440/how-do-i-attach-a-database-in-sql-server